# geting an empty dataframe after using the example code on googlefinance.client

Tags: python, google-finance-api

I am trying to run the sample code from the googlefinance.client 1.3.0 documentation after I install the package using pip install googlefinance.client

```
from googlefinance.client import get_price_data, get_prices_data, get_prices_time_data
# Dow Jones param = {
    'q': ".DJI", # Stock symbol (ex: "AAPL")
    'i': "86400", # Interval size in seconds ("86400" = 1 day intervals)
    'x': "INDEXDJX", # Stock exchange symbol on which stock is traded (ex: "NASD")
    'p': "1Y" # Period (Ex: "1Y" = 1 year) }
# get price data (return pandas dataframe) df = get_price_data(param) print(df)
```

However, instead of getting a dataset of price, i got an empty dataframe

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Open, High, Low, Close, Volume]
Index: []
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks!